# How can I access an SSAS cube in Oracle Apex?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-apex, ssas

I have an SSAS cube hosted on a SQL Server Analysis Services instance and I want to retrieve data from it in my Oracle Apex application. What is the best way to achieve this? Are there any specific tools or libraries that I can use for this integration? Any guidance or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Apex is installed within an Oracle database. (Apex) admin - while creating workspaces - specifies which **Oracle** schema(s) are available to it.

It means that you have to have a schema in Oracle database which is capable of accessing data from MS SQL Server database. I haven't done that *for ages* so technology might have improved since, but - at a time, it was **database link** between Oracle and MS SQL Server (hint: [heterogeneous connectivity](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/toc.htm)).

Then, you could create a view (in Oracle schema) as e.g.

```
create or replace view v_mssql_customer as
  select * from customer@dblink_to_mssql_server;
```

which should be enough for Apex to create e.g. Interactive Report whose source is a simple

```
select * from v_mssql_customer;
```